# How To install ASP 4.5 when VS 2012 is installed

Tags: asp.net-4.5

I want to install ASP 4.5 on a machine where Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 is installed.

.net 4.5 is installed with visual studio. So on this machines there is no 4.5 folder in %Windows%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64 theres only v4.0.30319 which is .net 4.0.

So I can't run aspnet_regiis -i  because I don't have a 4.5 folder...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.NET 4.5 is an in-place update to .NET 4.0.  Just follow the normal aspnet_regiis steps for v4.0.

When you go into inetmgr and select which version of the CLR to use for a given application pool, select CLR version 4.0 (which runs .NET Framework 4.5).  This is similar to how the CLR version 2.0 runs .NET Framework 2.0, 3.0, and 3.5.